# Regex : ignore HTML Tags with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to grab all text between the HTML Tags (if there), and put a function on it ..
i mean.. my code now is

```
$code = preg_replace_callback('/(\(\s*\')\s*(.*?)\s*(\')/',
        function($matches) {
            return strtolower($matches);
        }, $code);
```

now what i want is :

1. If there is a HTML tags    === Return HTML tags + strtolower(for the text between the tags).
2. If there isn't a HTML tags === Return strtolower(all the text)

---

example :
if we have :

```
('TEST HERE this is a TEXT')
```

return

```
('test here this is a text')
```

---

but if with HTML tags like

```
<DIV CLASS='tesT'>This IS A TEXT</DIV><Div class='Test1'>THIS is another TEXT</DIV>
```

return

```
<DIV CLASS='tesT'>this is a text</DIV><Div class='Test1'>this is another text</DIV>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_match easiest way to match text from inside html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843516/preg-match-easiest-way-to-match-text-from-inside-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback( '/(<.+?>)*(.*?)/s', 'replace', $str );

function replace( $matches ) {
    return $matches[1].strtolower( $matches[2] );
}
```

Comment: good code, but the problem is (its not ignore. its delete it)..
my pattern is `(\(\s*\')(<.+?>)*\s*(.*?)\s*(\')` and the function is: `return $matches[1].$matches[2].strtolower($matches[3]).$matches[4];`

Comment: @programmer4me my code doesn't delete anything, does exactly what you want, I've tested it.

Comment: ok good, im trying to make it works but the problem is im using this code .
`$code = preg_replace_callback('/(\(\')(<.+?>)*(.*?)(<.+?>)*(\')/',
            function($matches){
                var_dump($matches);
            }, $code);`
this code is not working, the matches dont view any html tags .. the matches[2] is empty ..
what's problem ?? thanks